# I am trying to populate a DOJO pie chart from a json array created by a url

Tags: json, dojo, pie-chart

I am trying to populate a dojo pie chart from a json array created by a url.

the url returns an array that looks like this

> {"pieItems":[["IPv4 TCP",475919493840],["IPv6 TCP",37443255432],["IPv4 UDP",34595392128],["IPv6 ICMP",14496],["IPv4 ICMP",46560],["IP Other",12385112]]}

I have attempted to redo the format of the array changing it to one that looks like this

> {"IPv4 TCP":[475919493840],"IPv6 TCP":[37443255432],"IPv4 UDP":[34595392128],"IPv6 ICMP":[14496],"IPv4 ICMP":[46560],"IP Other":[12385112]} .

the code I used to change the format is:

```
var len = responseObj.pieItems.length, i, hash = {};
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        hash[responseObj.pieItems[i][0]] = responseObj.pieItems[i][1];
    }
```

After changing the format I can only populate the chart with on item by adding the series and specifying the name.

> chart1.addSeries("IP Other",  hash["IPv6 ICMP"])

This populates the chart with that one item but if i try to add another series for example

> chart1.addSeries("IP Other",  hash["IPv4 Other"])

It overwrites the chart and shows the data for IP Other instead of adding another slice.

How can I add all the items in the array into the pie chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie chart supports just one series object by definition. You should add different data points for different slices. A sketch:

```
chart.addSeries("IP", dojo.map(responseObj, function(p){
  return {
    y:    p[1], // value
    text: p[0]  // label
  };
});
```

Comment: If i wanted to do this for bar graph how would i do this.  I am now trying to make a bar graph but this mapping doesnt seem to show the data